# Validate Json - Laravel

Tags: json, laravel-5

Hello I'm new in laravel and have some strange situation:

in laravel api.php I have route

```
Route::get('/blog', function() {
    $url_query_string = "format=json";
    $request_url = 'https://www.squarespace.com/templates/?' . $url_query_string;
    $ch = curl_init($request_url);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'H.H\'s PHP CURL script');
    $response_body = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);


    $res = json_decode($response_body,true);
    echo json_encode($res);
});
```

so it is working but not gives me validated json it is not correct look at picture

[image]

not sure where is a problem?

Comment: did you try without `json_decode` ?

Comment: yes, it shows me same results. json is really correct but when parsing something is happening

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this adding `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

```
$res = json_decode($response_body,true);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this small piece of code

```
if($request->isJson()) {
   if(empty($request->json()->all())) {
      echo "Invalid Json"
      //Put invalid JSON handling functions here
   } else {
      echo "Valid JSON"
      //Put you regular functions here because the input JSON is valid
      // Even if you don't put the else clause it is ok the code will continue executing further
 }
}
```